# Way to send OpenCV Mat to MATLAB workspace without copying the data?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

When I write MEX files which use OpenCV functions it's easy to pass the data **from** MATLAB to the MEX environment without copying the data. Is there a way to return the data **to** MATLAB in the same manner? (That is, without copying the data and without causing MATLAB to crash...)

A simple example:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "/opencv2/core.hpp"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    Rows=mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    Cols=mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    Mat InMat(Cols,Rows,CV_64FC1,mxGetPr(prhs[0]));//Matlab passes data column-wise 
                                                   // no need to copy data - SUPER!

    InMat=InMat.t();//transpose so the matrix is identical to MATLAB's one

    //Make some openCV operations on InMat to get OutMat...


    //Way of preventing the following code??

    plhs[0]=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(OutMat.rows,OutMat.cols,mxREAL);
    double *pOut=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    for (int i(0);i<OutMat.rows;i++)
      for (int j(0);j<OutMat.cols;j++)
         pOut[i+j*OutMat.rows]=OutMat.at<double>(i,j);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually I do the input and output just like that, attaching a pointer to deal with the input and looping over elements on output.  But, I think the output can be done in a similar manner to the input, although not without a copy of some sort.  The only way to avoid a copy is to create the output `Mat` with a pointer from a `mxArray` and operate on it inplace.  That's not always possible, of course.  But you can be graceful about how you copy the data out.

You can exploit the same trick of attaching a buffer to a `cv::Mat` that you use (me too!) to bring data in from MATLAB, but also to get it out.  The twist on the trick to exporting the data is to use [`copyTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto) just right so that it will use the existing buffer, the one from the `mxArray` in `plhs[i]`.

Starting with an input like this:

```
double *img = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
cv::Mat src = cv::Mat(ncols, nrows, CV_64FC1, img).t(); // nrows <-> ncols, transpose
```

You perform some operation, like resizing:

```
cv::Mat dst;
cv::resize(src, dst, cv::Size(0, 0), 0.5, 0.5, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

To get `dst` into MATLAB: **first** transpose the output (for sake of reordering the data into col-major order) **then** create an output `cv::Mat` with the pointer from the `plhs[0]` `mxArray`, and **finally** call `copyTo` to fill out the wrapper `Mat` with the transposed data:

```
dst = dst.t(); // first!
cv::Mat outMatWrap(dst.rows, dst.cols, dst.type(), pOut); // dst.type() or CV_*
dst.copyTo(outMatWrap); // no realloc if dims and type match
```

It is very important to get the dimensions and data type exactly the same for the following call to `copyTo` to keep from reallocating `outMatWrap`.

Note that when `outMatWrap` is destroyed, the `data` buffer will not be deallocated because the reference count is 0 (`Mat::release()` does not deallocate `.data`).

---

**Possible template** (by no means bullet-proof!)

```
template <typename T>
void cvToMATLAB(cv::Mat mat, T *p)
{
    CV_Assert(mat.elemSize1() == sizeof(T));
    mat = mat.t();
    cv::Mat outMatWrap(mat.rows, mat.cols, mat.type(), p);
    mat.copyTo(outMatWrap);
}
```

This should be good for channels>1, as long as the size of the MATLAB array is in pixel order too (e.g. 3xMxN). Then use `permute` as needed.

---

**Note about `copyTo`**

The conditions under which `copyTo` will reallocate the destination buffer are if the dimensions or data type do not match:

**opencv2\core\mat.hpp** line 347 (version 2.4.10), with my comments:

```
inline void Mat::create(int _rows, int _cols, int _type)
{
    _type &= TYPE_MASK;
    if( dims <= 2 && rows == _rows && cols == _cols && type() == _type && data )
        return;    // HIT THIS TO USE EXISTING BUFFER!
    int sz[] = {_rows, _cols};
    create(2, sz, _type); // realloc!
}
```

So, just make sure you get the size and data type correct, and the data will end up in the `mxArray` buffer instead of somewhere else.  If you do it right, `copyTo` will use the buffer you specified, calling `memcpy` on each row.